# Spring Data enum usage for in clause

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have an entity define below

```
@Entity
public class MyActions {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private MyEnum name;//this is a varchar in table definition

  private String description;
}
```

I have define spring repository interface and query as follows

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyActions, Long> {
    MyActions findByName(MyEnum name);

    @Query("from MyActions p where p.name in :actions")
    List<MyActions> findAllByName(@Param("actions") List<MyEnum> actions);
}
```

I have tested with single enum call (findByName method) and it works fine. But if i call the second one, findAllByName with a list of MyEnum, I start getting error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [CREATE] did not match expected type [com.MyEnum (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [CREATE] did not match expected type [com.MyEnum (n/a)]
```

Possible values in MyEnum are CREATE, PROCESS, SAVED .etc. I have tried various combinations , but it does not work. can you tell me how can this be made to work

Frameworks:

```
spring-data-jpa:2.6.4
hibernate-core:5.6.7
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue. There is some issue in the enum list generation. Found that List had underlying data as string. I am debugging why this happened, but the query works properly. I am using java 11. since the premise of the problem has changed , i will close the question. Thanks